# Compiling Assets (Laravel Mix) doesn't work for some dependencies

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

Currently, my `package.json` contains somes dev dependencies :

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "unslider": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.3.2"
},
...
```

When I first compiled all dependencies with `npm run dev`, eveything worked fine.

Then, I tried to install some others dependencies like `unslider`, as you can see. But now, I cannot understand why this package is not compiled in my `app.js` / `app.css`. I am missing something ?

Comment: paste the debug show when you run **npm run dev**

Comment: I can show you the debug, however there is no bug, no trace about this, eveything is compiled successfully.

Comment: do you update the asset file to compile it with other?

Comment: Hum what do you mean ? I did not understand.

Comment: how you install **unslider** using npm install or what? and after that do you make the necessary change in **resources/assets/js** and may **resources/assets/sass** or **resources/assets/less**?

Comment: I installed *unslider* with npm, then run *npm run dev*, that's all. I didn't know that I had to do this. Sould I include anything more in those files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after review the package in github, you have to add this:

In **resources/assets/sass/app.scss**:

```
@import "node_modules/unslider/src/scss/unslider.scss"
```

In **resources/assets/js/app.js**:

```
require('unslider');
```